# How to incorporate two filters on the same field for a comparison chart

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to be able to add two filters on the same field in order to plot a comparison of values for two bands.
What is the way to proceed?

Ultimately I would like to generate the figure from the table below, by being able to dynamically select A/B bands from two different filters. In this case, Filter1=A and Filter2= C were selected to compute Filter1-Filter2 across the dimension 'Type'.

[image]

[image]

I have tried duplicating the filter but when choosing a band, it affects both filters.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is with two Parameters.  Each should have its values generated from the field (in your case, A/B).  The create a single filter (calculated field) that says "[parameter1]=[field A/B] or [parameter2]=[field A/B]".  Put the filter on the filter shelf and set it to true.

Now you have two "filters" (parameters) that can both drive the single field.